# Calculating last ended week in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a query on a database using the timestamp. Right now i'm using hardcoded dates for the query,

```
$dd1 = 20;//date("d",$ddb1);
    $mm1 = date("m");
    $yyyy1 = date("Y");
    $dd2 = 26;//date("d",$ddb2);
    $mm2 = date("m");
    $yyyy2 = date("Y");
```

But i need the code to calculate last weeks data (Monday to Sunday), whenever i run the scrip. For example, i run the scrip today (Wensday) so the calculated time should be last week from (Monday to Sunday). The same result should be in any other days of this week untill 12:00:01 Sunday night.

Tried to do something like:

```
    //$ddb1 = time() - ($argv[1] * 24 * 60 * 60);
    //$ddb2 = time() - ($argv[2] * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

To substract a number of days from the current date, but there must be a automatic way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$first_day = strtotime('Last Week');
$last_day = strtotime('Last Sunday');

echo "Last Monday was ".date('m-d-Y', $first_day);
echo "Last Sunday was ".date('m-d-Y', $last_day);

#Last Monday was 08-27-2012
#Last Sunday was 09-02-2012
```

Comment: No, this will return last Monday, September 3, not last weeks Monday, August 27.

Comment: What if you do the query on Monday? they you get 2 weeks interval

Comment: No, he's right, you need to take 7 days off the last Sunday value to get the first day of last week

Comment: @user1579135 never mind, that is my code and I'm 100% it works without any magic numbers.

Comment: @MihaiIorga See my edit, I ran the code today (Wednesday 5th September 2012) to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

```
$lastsunday=strtotime("last Sunday");
$lastmonday=strtotime("last Sunday")-(7*86400);
```

Edit:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/NSW');
    $lastSunday=strtotime("last Sunday");
    $lastMonday=strtotime("last Sunday")-(6*86400);

    echo "Last Sunday was ".date('d-m-Y', $lastSunday)."<br>";
    echo "Last Monday was ".date('d-m-Y', $lastMonday);
    
?>
```

Output:

```
Last Sunday was 02-09-2012
Last Monday was 27-08-2012
```

Comment: Mihai is right, you need to extract 6 days for the code to work corectly :) but both of you guys helped me a lot, thanks

Comment: @MihaiIorga Okay, I just got it. *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

get the last Sunday:

```
$last_sunday = strtotime('Last Sunday');
```

then substract 6 days to get the last monday:

```
$last_monday = date($last_sunday-86400*6)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
/**
* int nth_day_of_month(int $nbr, str $day, int $mon, int $year)
*   $nbr = nth weekday to find
*   $day = full name of weekday, e.g. "Saturday"
*   $mon = month 1 - 12
*   $year = year 1970, 2007, etc.
* returns UNIX time
*/

function nth_day_of_month($nbr, $day, $mon, $year)
{
   $date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mon, 0, $year);
   if($date == 0)
   {
      user_error(__FUNCTION__."(): Invalid month or year", E_USER_WARNING);
      return(FALSE);
   }
   $day = ucfirst(strtolower($day));
   if(!in_array($day, array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
         'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')))
   {
      user_error(__FUNCTION__."(): Invalid day", E_USER_WARNING);
      return(FALSE);
   }
   for($week = 1; $week <= $nbr; $week++)
   {
      $date = strtotime("next $day", $date);
   }
   return($date);
} 


function getWeekNoByDay($year = 2007,$month = 5,$day = 1) {
    return ceil(($day + date("w",mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)))/7);
}
```